# d3js - how to set albers projection properly?

Tags: d3.js

I have some geojson data for Japan, which I managed to position properly on a mercator projection, but I'm a bit lost as to how to position it properly using an albers projection, other than trial and error.

Is there a good tool to use?

blocks example: http://bl.ocks.org/4043986

long, lat for japan ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan)):

- latitudes 24° - 46°N,
- longitudes 122° - 146°E.

geojson link: https://gist.github.com/raw/4043986/f53b85ab0af1585cd0461b4865ca4acd1fb79e9f/japan.json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer looking through the repository - the tool is right there!

1. clone d3.js from [the github repository](https://github.com/mbostock/d3).
2. edit [/d3/examples/albers.html line 53](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/cdffe18d383e47f77d6388f875a377539b20dcd2/examples/albers/albers.html#L53) to point at your GEOJSON file:
3. Put the origin long / lat sliders to the center of your country / region (for me, it was 134° / 25°)
4. Change the paralells to be as close to the edges of your country / region.
5. adjust scale & offset to a nice size & position.

There are similar tools for the other projections.

edit: The repository has changed (and is constantly changing), so I've created a gist to preserve the example: https://gist.github.com/4552802

The examples are no longer part of the github repository.

Comment: Hi none of the above links are working. Can you please update them.

Comment: I updated the link to point at an older revision of the file. Also, check the gist I have linked.

Comment: please update the correct jquery etc links since ones I tried shows only a circle on rendering the albers.html you have.  I did just steps 1,2 you mentioned thinking rest I need to do after page is rendered.  I am trying for India region and geojson I created using https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/ places.json step.

Answer (score 18):

As of now, it's the version 3 of D3.js.
It might be worth looking at the original source [albers.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/geo/albers.js) at github, which contains :

```
d3.geo.albers = function() {
    return d3.geo.conicEqualArea()
      .parallels([29.5, 45.5])
      .rotate([98, 0])
      .center([0, 38])
      .scale(1000);
};
```

Now, d3.js use combination of `projection.rotate` and `projection.center` to place center of the projection to long 98°W, lat 38°N (around [Hutchinson, Kansas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hutchinson,_Kansas)).

From [Geo Projections API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-conicEqualArea_parallels),`d3.geo.conicEqualArea()
      .parallels([29.5, 45.5])` sets the Albers projection’s two standard parallels latitudes 29.5°N and
45.5°N, respectively. But what is two standard parallels?

To understand what parallels setting is, one need to know that Albers projection is a kind of conic projection.

*A conic projection projects information from the spherical Earth to a cone that is either tangent to the Earth at a single parallel, or that is secant at two standard parallels.*

[image]

Choosing the best standard parallels setting seems to be a subtle task, of which the goal is to minimize the projection distortion when mapping between surfaces. Anyway, choosing the two values to be closed to a country top/bottom edges is intuitively good, as it helps minimize the distance between the [conic/sphere] surfaces enclosing a country.
[image]